# pgAdmin4 Query Tool is not getting connected

Tags: pgadmin, ubuntu-18.04, pgadmin-4

I am new to pgAdmin and pgAdmin4. I have installed it through Python Wheel(I'm new to that too)

It works better than pgAdmin3 but when I close my google chrome browser and restart the pgAdmin localhost server then all works well except the query tool. It's always showing disconnected icon. I'm unable to execute the query. Also, I don't know where to check for the possible error.

Though when I delete the connection and recreate the connection from the beginning it works.

Comment: A bug is already reported to pgAdmin4 team https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was issue from PgAdmin side and was resolved in next updates.

Issue Link: [redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3679](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3679)